# Simple shortcode woes, coding for dummies

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

been asked to help a friend display some custom data on a Wordpress site, easy I thought...

Have a table with customer data in. Idea a plugin to is to query the table based on current user id and spit it out as shortcodes so they can place the output where ever they like.

After much googling (I'm not a coder) I got something that worked! Problem is, even to my untrained eye, it looks like a bodge, repeating queries when there's clearly a more intelligent way of doing it.... Can someone clever please show me the way based on the this >> ?

```
<?php

  Plugin Name: do stuff

  Description: Do site specific stuff


function spend_data() {

  global $wpdb;

  global $current_user;

  wp_get_current_user();

  $userid = $current_user->ID;

  $spend = $wpdb->get_var ( "SELECT spend FROM mytable WHERE the_id=$userid");

        return $spend;
}

function detail_data() {

  global $wpdb;

  global $current_user;

  wp_get_current_user();

  $userid = $current_user->ID;

  $detail = $wpdb->get_var ( "SELECT detail FROM mytable WHERE the_id=$userid");

        return $programs;
}

add_shortcode('spend', 'spend_data');

add_shortcode('detail', 'detail_data');

/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
```

Comment: a function when invokes returns a valu in your case for spend_data the amount of mony the curent looged in user has spend.(and so on and so on.  the last to code lines shows you, wehat you have to add in your page to show that information to the loggin in user.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to SO. This doesn't look too bad to me, if it's only these 2 shortcodes. Do you have performance issues?

Comment: Thanks Snuwerd! It's going to be more than two, maybe 10/12. I'm sure the server will survive, it just doesn't seem to be very elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do a query for all fields at a hook that fires before the shortcodes and then store it all in `$current_user`. Don't forget to replace `mytable` with the correct tablename.

```
function marks_prepare_user_shortcodes () {
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $current_user->ID;

    $row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE the_id=".$userid, ARRAY_A);

    $current_user->marks_shortcodes = $row; 
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'marks_prepare_user_shortcodes');
```

And then your shortcodes change to

```
function spend_data() {
    global $current_user;
    $spend = $current_user->marks_shortcodes['spend'];
    if (!is_null($spend))
        return $spend;
}

function detail_data() {
    global $current_user;
    $detail = $current_user->marks_shortcodes['detail'];
    if (!is_null($detail))
        return $detail;
}

add_shortcode('spend', 'spend_data');
add_shortcode('detail', 'detail_data');
```

I'm not sure if `wp_head` is the correct /best action to pick here, you could give it a try. I figured it is called before all the shortcodes are. Code is untested.

Ps. As a sidenote, I believe your extra user data should actually be stored in the `wp_usermeta` table, instead of a separate table. You'd retrieve the fields with `get_user_meta()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

**Update**

Instead of the code block directly above, you could also use this:

```
function mikes_data_shortcode($atts) {
    global $current_user;

    $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);

    // override default attributes with user attributes
    $actual_atts = shortcode_atts([
                                     'field' => 'YouDidntEnterAFieldNameAsAttribute',
                                 ], $atts); 

    $data = $current_user->marks_shortcodes[$actual_atts['field']];
    if (!is_null($data))
        return $data;   
}

function mikes_shortcodes_init()
{
    add_shortcode('mikes_data_shortcode', 'mikes_data_shortcode');
}

add_action('init', 'mikes_shortcodes_init');
```

Where you use shortcodes like this:

`[mikes_data_shortcode field="spend"]`

or

`[mikes_data_shortcode field="detail"]`

Comment: possibly, but I can't help it but think it looks something more like this?

function all_the_data() {
$stuff = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE the_id=$userid");
return $stuff;
}

add_shortcode('stuff', 'all_the_data');
<br>And page shortcode looks like >
[stuff 'spend']
[stuff 'detail']

With one query and parameters in the shortcode?

Comment: You are right about the second part, it actually crossed my mind to make parameters for the shortcode, but I thought it was out of scope. One moment.

Comment: Added way to request fields as parameters in the shortcode. I made it `echo` instead of `return` btw.

Comment: Sorry, pi-hole went on strike so chose wine over websites :)  

Put data in a separate table as I'm not sure how it's going to be imported/updated, thought safer to keep it away from core WP tables!  

Looks like your answer is what I'm after, just got to persuade WP to play ball now, rather than spitting out 'Warning: Attempt to assign property 'marks_shortcodes' of non-object' & 'Undefined variable: tag in' & Illegal string offset 'spend' in' & 'Uninitialized string offset: 0 in' etc etc

Comment: I'm just getting the above errors at the mo, will try and figure out how the code works later to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Please try the code at the top (first block) and the last block of code together. There was a small mistake in the first, and I removed the tag error by changing the last block.

Comment: So, full plugin is this (no idea how to format a comment, sorry....)

Comment: Ok, so can't post it!

Comment: Both blocks together in a plugin. line 15 =     $userid->marks_shortcodes = $row;

Comment: Give error > Warning: Attempt to assign property 'marks_shortcodes' of non-object in line 15

Comment: Line 30 =    $data = $current_user->marks_shortcodes[$actual_atts['field']];

Comment: Give errors >  Illegal string offset 'spend' in line 30 & Uninitialized string offset: 0 in line 30

Comment: 'marks_shortcodes' is referenced in your code but doesn't seem to be defined?

Comment: My apologies, copy the first block again. I was saving `marks_shortcodes` in `$userid` instead of `$current_user` by accident. I don't know how I made so many mistakes in that first block.

Comment: Jedi! No more errors being reported! But also nothing being returned by the shortcode, [mikes_data_shortcode field="spend"] should return the column value of 3500 in my example data....

Comment: Let me do some testing, also, did you replace mytable with the correct table in the first block of code?

Comment: It's working for me, so I think you didn't replace the table name.

Comment: Table name is correct, noticed that your select was > $row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE the_id=".$userid, ARRAY_A); closes before user id is passed? Should this be > $row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_pge WHERE pge_id=$userid", ARRAY_A); ?

Comment: No, both are correct. Can you send a screenshot of the column names of the table in the database?

Comment: Also, I should not have changed the `echo` to `return`, so I changed it back. That is likely the problem since there are no more errors.

Comment: You're wecome, Mark!